# Присвоенный класс не хочет работать

Tags: javascript, jquery, классы

Доброго времени суток всем, нужна небольшая помощь. Навешиваю на класс проверку с помощью `.append()` и добавляю объект с этим классом, но он упрямо отказывается работать, если кто знает как решить проблему подскажите пожалуйста. Вот немного кода, так наверно будет понятней:

```
  $('.number2').bind("keyup", function() {
  if(this.value.match(/[,]/g))this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g , ".");
  if (this.value.match(/[^0-9/./,]/g)) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9/./,]/g, '');
  }});

 function builder (){
    $("#bigTable").empty();
    var rows = $("#rows").val();
    var cols = $("#cols").val();

    var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('foo');
    for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
        var row = $('<tr></tr>');
        for(var j=0; j<cols; j++){
            var col = $('<td><label><input class="number2"></label></td>');
            row.append(col);
        }
        table.append(row);
    }
    $('#bigTable').append(table);
 }
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Когда выполняется

```
$('.number2').bind("keyup",
```

элементов с классом `number2` еще нет.

Делегирование http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".number2", function() {
  ...
});
```